# Where exists SQL with internal where condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following request, to say more precise the SQL parameterized query:

```
select * from `products` 
where (exists (select * from `productslocation` where `products`.`Id` = `productslocation`.`Product_Id` and `Country_Id` = ?) and 
exists (select * from `productprices` where `products`.`Id` = `productprices`.`Products_Id` and `Price` >= ?) 
and `Organization_Id` = ? and `name` like ? or `Description` like ?) and `Status` = ?
```

This query retrieves only products where exist `country`, `price` using operator `WHERE EXISTS`.

If it was found it returns `TRUE` for first sub query, then works remaining two queries `WHERE`. First sub query returns `TRUE`, second gives `TRUE`, cause sub query is right also. `result = TRUE * TRUE = TRUE`. But it is wrong result.

Problem is, that need to use two intern queries WHERE for result from `WHERE EXISTS`.

Does it mean I need to replace `WHERE EXISTS` ON `JOIN'S`? Or is it possible to modify query above?

Comment: I use WHERE EXISTS for filtering products by properties, it is very convenient, but when I want to filter result data in the table itself, it gives wrong result corresponding logic of WHERE EXISTS.

Comment: Seems in my case `WHERE Organization_Id` = ? and `name` like ? or `Description` like ?` should be placed in each sub queries, is not ?

Comment: Your EXISTS statements look fine. I think your problem is that you are mixing AND and OR statements in the WHERE clause on the products table itself. Whenever I use an OR I immediately start using parenthesis to be clear. My guess is order-of-precedence in processing the AND and OR statements is what is giving you unexpected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parentheses and `OR`s and `AND`s are making the statement very complicated. 
Try this:

```
    select * from `products` 
    where 
    (
    exists (select * from `productslocation` where `products`.`Id` = `productslocation`.`Product_Id` and `Country_Id` = ?) and 
    exists (select * from `productprices` where `products`.`Id` = `productprices`.`Products_Id` and `Price` >= ?) and 
    `Organization_Id` = ? and (`name` like ? or `Description` like ?) and `Status` = ?
    )
```

Comment: Do you know how to write this in Laravel, I mean brackets, when I use some where?

Comment: No, never dealt with Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

It's not better that way? Try this:

```
select * from `products` inner join productprices on `products`.`Id` = `productprices`.`Products_Id`
INNER JOIN `productslocation` ON `products`.`Id` = `productslocation`.`Product_Id`
where (`Organization_Id` = ? and `name` like ? or `Description` like ?) and `Status` = ? 
AND `productprices`.`Price` >= ?
and `productslocation`.Country_Id` = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed brackets around your or statement:

```
select * from `products` 
where (exists (select * from `productslocation` where `products`.`Id` = `productslocation`.`Product_Id` and `Country_Id` = ?) and 
exists (select * from `productprices` where `products`.`Id` = `productprices`.`Products_Id` and `Price` >= ?) 
and `Organization_Id` = ? and (`name` like ? or `Description` like ?)) and `Status` = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a query that filters `products` on various criteria, some involving referential relationships.

Assuming that you have `1-1` relationships with the referential tables, you should be able to use `JOIN`s :

```
select *
from 
    `products` 
    inner join `productslocation` 
        on `products`.`Id` = `productslocation`.`Product_Id` and `productslocation`.`Country_Id` = ?
    inner join `productprices` 
        on  `products`.`Id` = `productprices`.`Products_Id` and `productprices`.`Price` >= ?
where
    `products`.`Organization_Id` = ? 
    and `products`.`name` like ? 
    and `products`.`Description` like ?
    and `products`.`Status` = ?
```